# Server quit without updating PID file on multiple mysql installation in linux

Tags: linux, mysql, database, installation

Iam trying to install one version of mysql in a LINUX  machine. The system contain already another version of mysql installation. I prefer manual installation. Copy the extracted tarball into a location and create symbolic link to that. I wish to install my mysql version without affecting already installed mysql version in the system.

I created mysqld(with a unique name `mysqltest`) as service. But it couldn't start. When Iam trying to start this mysqld process, it shows an error like:

```
Starting MySQL............................................................
......................................... 
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file ((/usr/local/mysqltest/data/Test.pid).
```

After getting this error, I gave full permission to the tree path directories. Then I can trying to start the service again. But it shows another error:

```
Warning: World-writable config file '/usr/local/mysqltest/my.cnf' is ignored
Starting MySQL..................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/test.pid).
```

Please help me, is any wrong with my installation???

I follow the below mentioned link for installion : http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/manually-installing-multiple-mysql-instances-on-linux-howto

This is my my.cnf file contents:

```
    [mysql]
    port=3351
    socket=/tmp/mysqltest.sock

    [mysqld]
    port=3351
    socket=/tmp/mysqltest.sock
    datadir=/usr/local/mysqltest/data

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/usr/local/mysqltest/mysqldtest.log
    pid-file=/usr/local/mysqltest/mysqldtest.pid
```

Comment: What do you log files say ? Mysql log files end in .err and are usually somewhere in and around the data directory.